# Solve an intergral in R: the integrand is a function of the solution of an ODE

Tags: r, math

I would like to compute an integral where the integrand is a function of the solution of an ODE.

In order to solve the integral, R needs to solve an ODE for each value the integration algorithm uses. This is what I have done so far:

```
require(deSolve)

# Function to be passed to zvode in order to solve the ODE  
ODESR <- function(t, state, parameters) {
   with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
       dPSI <- -kappa*PSI+0.5*sigma^2*PSI^2
       dPHI <- kappa*theta*PSI
       return(list(c(dPSI, dPHI)))
   })
}

# For a given value of p this code should return the solution of the integral
pdfSRP <- function (p) {
   integrand <- function (u) {
       state <- c(PSI = u*1i, PHI = 0)
       out <- as.complex(zvode(y = state, times = times, parms = parameters, fun = ODESR)[2, 2:3])
       Re(exp(out[2] + out[1]*x)*exp(-u*1i*p))
   }
integrate(f = integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)$value/(2*pi)
}
```

For the following given values:

```
parameters <- c(kappa = 1, theta = 0.035, sigma = 0.05)
times <- c(0,1)
x <- 0.1
```

running:

```
pdfSRP(p = 2)
```

produces the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'PSI' not found
```

I just cannot figure out why. I'm quite sure it is due to a syntax error, because running:

```
integrand <- function (u) {
       state <- c(PSI = u*1i, PHI = 0)
       out <- as.complex(zvode(y = state, times = times, parms = parameters, fun = ODESR)[2, 2:3])
       Re(exp(out[2] + out[1]*x)*exp(-u*1i*p))
}
```

with `p <- 2` and (for example) `u <- 3` works.

Can you help me spot the mistake?

Comment: Hi!
Only a short comment: you have a problem with your variable `u`. Try
`print(state)` after your definition of the state variables `state` and you'll see that `u` has length 15 and not 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a vectorization problem in the `integrand` input `u`. If I understand correctly, `PSI` should be a number for each calculation and not a vector of numbers (which will give a dimensional problem between `PSI` and `PHI`. Hence

```
integrand <- Vectorize(integrand)
```

should resolve your issue. From `?integrate`:

> f must accept a vector of inputs and produce a vector of function evaluations at those points.

---

However, this leads to a different error.

```
pdfSRP(p = 2)
## Error in integrate(f = integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf) : 
## the integral is probably divergent
```

If we plot the integrand, we may spot the divergence problem

```
p <- 2
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
curve(integrand,-1e3,1e3,n = 100)
curve(integrand,-1e3,1e3,n = 1e3)
```

[image: integrand plot with different amount of evaluation points]

Assuming the integrand converges sufficiently fast to zero in both tails, the divergence of the integral could be a result from numerical imprecision. We can increase precision by increasing the number of subintervals for the integral, which does give a result - I suppose, as expected by heuristically looking at the plot.

```
pdfSRP <- function (p) {
    int <- integrate(f = integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
                    subdivisions = 1e3)
    int$value/(2*pi)
}
## [1] 2.482281e-06
```

Comment: Let me know if the second part of the answer is unhelpful, and I will delete it, since it is not directly a response to your question. :)

Comment: Thanks it works! The second part of the answer is very helpful. Please do not delete it :).  Just to be sure that I did everything right: is it correct that R prints a lot of values before printing the final solution?

Comment: `pdfSRP` should only return one value, `int$value/(2*pi)` ("the final estimate of the integral" per `?integrate`). If you get intermediate results, perhaps you have a `print` or `cat` somewhere?

Comment: By the comment on your question, perhaps look for a forgotten testing statement `print(state)` that was suggested by J_M :)

Comment: Yep, you were right. I forgot to remove that `print()`... Thank you so much for your help!